# search bar not working?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

i have a SQL file where 5 different type of data is stored. I am adding this data in a dictionary specified with keys. and then i am adding this dictionary to tableData array as a dataSource for table and searchBar. But it is not searching anything.

**adding code below**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


dataSource =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
searchedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Vegetables"];

SQLite *sqlObj1 = [[SQLite alloc] initWithSQLFile:@"ShoppersWorld.sqlite"];
[sqlObj1 openDb];
[sqlObj1 readDb:query];

    //  [query release];
for (int i=0; i<[dataSource count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"data:%@",[dataSource objectAtIndex:i]);
}

while ([sqlObj1 hasNextRow]) 
{

    NSString *name=[sqlObj1 getColumn:1 type:@"text"];
    NSString *price=[sqlObj1 getColumn:2 type:@"text"];
    NSString *quantity=[sqlObj1 getColumn:3 type:@"text"];
    NSString *unit=[sqlObj1 getColumn:4 type:@"text"];
    NSString *total=[sqlObj1 getColumn:5 type:@"text"]; 


    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: name,@"nameOfVegetables",
                                                                price,@"priceOfVegetables",
                                                                quantity,@"quantityOfVegetables",
                                                                unit,@"unitOfVegetables",
                                                                total,@"totalPriceOfVegetables",nil];


        //NSLog(@"results:%@ %@",dict);
    [dataSource addObject:dict];


}

[tableData  addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

    // Set up the cell...
    // Configure the cell.


else {

    cell.productLbl.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nameOfVegetables"] ];     
    cell.bPriceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs %d/Kg",
                                        [[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"priceOfVegetables"] intValue]]; 

    cell.qtyLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"QTY: %@ %@",[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                                                               objectForKey:@"quantityOfVegetables"],[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"unitOfVegetables"]] ;

    cell.tPriceLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TOTAL: %@",[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                                    objectForKey:@"totalPriceOfVegetables"]];

}
return cell;
}
```

#pragma search operations

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender{

sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,30)];
sBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:sBar];

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    // only show the status bar’s cancel button while in edit mode
[sBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
sBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    // flush the previous search content
[tableData removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

[sBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil){
        [tableview reloadData];
        return;

}
NSInteger counter = 0;
for(NSString *name in dataSource)

    for (int i = 0; i < [dataSource count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary*) [dataSource objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp valueForKey:@"nameOfVegetables"]];
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];      
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];        
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)            
        {           
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.                
            {               
                [tableData addObject:name];             
            }           
        }       
        counter++;      
        [pool release];
    }

[tableview reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

sBar.hidden= YES;
    // if a valid search was entered but the user wanted to cancel, bring back the main list content
[tableData removeAllObjects];
[tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];
@try{
    [tableview reloadData];
}
@catch(NSException *e){
}
[sBar resignFirstResponder];
sBar.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In search delegate methods you manipulate not with searchedData but tableData array. As these name suggest, array searchedData is supposed to store filtered data.

By the way, your approach to use sqlite for data source and absorbing all database into array is wrong. In cellForRowAtIndexPath read from sqlite database only data you need at the moment.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // load from sqlite only data for this cell.
   // Use searchBar.text with sqlite's LIKE to filter data from database
   NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SignsCellIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {                                       
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT fieldNameFromTable FROM TableName WHERE FieldToLookForIn LIKE \"%%%@%%\" LIMIT 1 OFFSET %u", searchBar.text ? searchBar.text : @"", row];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (res != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2() failed"];
        return nil;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const unsigned char *name = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);            
        cell.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)name];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
return cell;
}
```

How to apply search in this approach? In textDidChange do nothing but call [tableView reloadData]. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath load data with sqlite LIKE using searchBar.text as search term. So reloadData will load only filtered records. searchBarSearchButtonClicked will call only resignFirstResponder of it's caller, removing keyboard off screen. It doesn't need to do anything more because search is already done. searchBarCancelButtonClicked will set text property of it's caller to nil, call reload data and again call resignFirstResponder.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)s {
    s.text = nil;
    [tableView reloadData];
    [s resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)s {
    // search is already done
    [s resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection should also request db with the same SELECT as in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but with SELECT COUNT. Writing this method will be your homework)

Comment: CellForRowAtIndexPath load data with sqlite LIKE using searchBar.text as search term....sorry i dont understand this term...how to do this? explain with a dummy code please.

Comment: @@Valeriy Van how can we load data from sqlite to display cell data?

Comment: @Vikas Maini, I provided code for cellForRowAtIndexPath method with fetches data from sqlite database.